# How to download a jar from artifactory with gradle to project directory?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

What is the correct way to write a gradle task which downloads a .jar(or any other) file from artifactory to project directory(if file does not already exists)?

For example, I have a project with path `/root/project` with file `/root/project/build.gradle` inside. I want to download generator.jar from artifactory (com/company/project/generator/1.0) to `/root/project` directory if `/root/project/generator.jar` is not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tasks.register("downloadGeneratorJar") {
    group = 'Download'
    description = 'Downloads generator.jar'

doLast {
    def f = new File('generator.jar')
    if (!f.exists()) {
        URL artifactoryUrl = new URL('myurl')
        HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)artifactoryUrl.openConnection()

        String userCredentials = gradle.ext.developerUser + ":" + gradle.ext.developerPassword
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()))

        myURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth)
        InputStream is = myURLConnection.getInputStream()

        new FileOutputStream(f).withCloseable { outputStream ->
            int read
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]

            while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```